# Programmatically disable DEBUG in Django command

Tags: django, memory-management

I am using a custom Django command to generate XML sitemaps for a site with about 3-4 million data entries (`./manage.py generate_sitemaps`). This seems to work, but eats way too much memory when `DEBUG` is enabled in settings.py.

I usually have the `DEBUG` option enabled during development and frequently forget to disable it before starting the sitemap creation. If that happens, the memory starts filling up until the script crashes after about 2-3 hours. Very annoying.

Is there a way to temporarily disable the debug setting for the execution of a Django command? I thought of importing the settings module and overriding the option, but I don't think that'll work.

Comment: Is restarting your server an option? If so, you could use sed to set DEBUG = Off, restart your server and turn DEBUG on again afterwards ...

Comment: It's a Django command, which needs no running server. I can change the setting, start it and change it back, but that's exactly the thing I'm too lazy to do. If there would be a way to override it from my script, that would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have a couple of options here:

1. Import settings and throw an error to remind yourself to turn debug off.
2. Use the `--settings=` and set that equal to a file (e.g. gen_settings.py) file specifically for your generate_sitemaps command where `DEBUG=False`. Then create an alias for `./manage.py generate_sitemaps --settings=gen_settings`

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/ warns specifically to not change the settings at runtime

I've used the second option before and it worked fairly well. Better than being annoyed after 2-3 hours =)

Comment: I wonder if the warning not to change settings at runtime in the docs only applies to web-servers (maybe due to threading issues etc.) I have an unsupported hunch that it might be less problematic for management commands.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure it helps you, but you can try:

```
from django.conf import settings

tmp = settings.DEBUG
settings.DEBUG = False
# some your actions
# ...
# ...
settings.DEBUG = tmp
```

Alternatively you can use separated settings file and set it in command line like

```
./manage.py your_command --settings=another_settings.py
```

And in that another_settings.py:

```
from .settings import *
DEBUG = False
```

Comment: I don't think the 1rst solution will work, but the 2nd approach looks interesting :)